# Sending multiple forms with ajax to multiple actions

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

So, I have a page with two forms, one for login and another for register.

I have this script to send the form without reloading the page.

For login:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('submit', '#login', function()
    {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'login.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data)
            {
                $("#login").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                {
                    $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                    {
                        $(".result").html(data);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

For register:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('submit', '#register', function()
    {
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'register.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data)
            {
                $("#register").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                {
                    $(".result").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                    {
                        $(".result").html(data);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

My problem is, technically, the data for login goes to login.php and the data for register, to register.php. But when I submit the form, all the data (Register and login) goes to register.php.

I have this forms with id:

```html
<form class="col s12" method="POST" id="register">
    form inputs here
</form>
<form class="col s12" method="POST" id="login">
    form inputs here
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `action="login.php"` to the `<form ...>` tag?

Comment: Yes, With the action tag the forms don't work